# Compound Assignment Operator returning a wrong value (Decimal to Binary Conversion)

Tags: c, binary, decimal, compound-assignment

I'm trying to write a C Program to convert a Decimal to Binary. The following code can convert an Integer in Decimal to Binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long int n;
    printf("Enter a Positive Integer (decimal): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long int temp = n;
    int r;  long long int bin = 0;
    int p = 0;

    while(temp > 0)
    {
        r = temp % 2;   printf("%d\t", r); // printing r value for debugging
        bin += (r * pow(10, p));
        temp /= 2;
        p++;
    }
    printf("\n%lld", bin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested the code for multiple random values and got the expected output for most of them except two particular values '*99999*' and '*419862*'. For '*99999*', the expected output is '*11000011010011111*', But instead I get '*11000011010011112*'. And for '419862', the expected output is '*1100110100000010110*', But instead I get '*1100110100000010112*'. All digits but the last one's match correctly. Getting a '*2*' instead of '*1*' and '*0*'. To Debug the code I added a `printf("%d\t", r);` immediately after the `r = temp % 2;` statement. The **r values** so printed give the correct expected output. Here is the output:

For '99999' the output is

```
Enter a Positive Integer (decimal): 99999
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   
11000011010011112
```

For '419862' the output is

```
Enter a Positive Integer (decimal): 419862
0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   
1100110100000010112
```

Caution: The **r values** printed individually are in reverse.

Why is the first remainder value printed using `printf("%d\t", r);` '1' and '0' respectively
(for '*99999*' and '*419862*'), But the unit digits of **bin value** obtained by Compound Assignment not the same?

Comment: Might be because `pow` is returning a floating point value, which isn't exact. You can avoid `pow(10, p)` by starting `p` at 1 (which equals `pow(10, 0)`) and, instead of incrementing it, multiply it by 10 each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes, Apparently that was the problem. As you (@DanGetz) and @MikeCAT pointed it out. Also, using Explicit Type Conversion (long long int) pow(10, p) worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`bin += (r * pow(10, p));` means `bin = bin + (r * pow(10, p));`. ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.16.2 Compound assignment)

According to *usual arithmetic conversions* (N1570 6.3.1.8), multiplication `*` and addition `+` will yield `double` result when one of their operands is `double` (and the other one is real type and not `long double`).

The `pow` function (N1570 7.12.7.4) returns `double`, so `r * pow(10, p)` has type `double`, and therefore `bin + (r * pow(10, p))` also has type `double`.

Typically 64-bit IEEE754 format is used for `double`. It is said that the presicion of this format is about 15 decimal digits.

In the last iteration with input `99999`, values `1000011010011111` and `10000000000000000` are added. They has 16 and 17 digits, respectively.
This exceeds the 15-digit limit and the chance to get precision errors becomes high.

In conclusion, you are getting rounding error because you used floating-point values where integers with many digits should be used.

For example, the use of `pow` in this case can be eliminated in this way (use a multiplier variable `mult` and incrementaly multiply `10` to that instead calculating the power in each iteration):

```c
    long long int mult = 1;
    while(temp > 0)
    {
        r = temp % 2;   printf("%d\t", r); // printing r value for debugging
        bin += (r * mult);
        temp /= 2;
        mult *= 10;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped resolve the issue. Also, using Explicit Type Conversion (long long int) pow(10, p) worked as well.